# The getter 'difinition' isn't defined for the class 'Rx<WordTrans>'

Tags: flutter

I define an entity in flutter like this:

```
class WordTrans {
  WordTrans({required this.difinition});

  String difinition;
}
```

then I use the entity in [getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get) controller like this:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:reddwarfdict/src/models/word/word.dart';
import 'package:reddwarfdict/src/service/word/word_provider.dart';

class HomeController extends GetxController {
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  var wordTrans = WordTrans(difinition: "1").obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
  }

  void fetchSearchResult() async {
    isLoading(true);
    try {
      var result = await WordProvider.doSearch();
      wordTrans(result);
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
}
```

after get data from server side, update the `wordTrans`, then in the UI, I get the value like this way:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
   Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final HomeController _controller = Get.put(HomeController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return GetBuilder<HomeController>(
        init: HomeController(),
        builder: (controller) {
          return Scaffold(
            body:SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(_controller.wordTrans.difinition),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed:() {
                      _controller.fetchSearchResult();
                      },
                    child: Text("click"),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ) ,
          );
        });
  }
}
```

when I compile the project, shows error like this:

```
lib/src/pages/home/home.dart:23:46: Error: The getter 'difinition' isn't defined for the class 'Rx<WordTrans>'.
 - 'Rx' is from 'package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_types.dart' ('../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.3.8/lib/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_types.dart').
 - 'WordTrans' is from 'package:reddwarfdict/src/models/word/word.dart' ('lib/src/models/word/word.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'difinition'.
                  Text(_controller.wordTrans.difinition),
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

what should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Try `_controller.wordTrans.value.difinition`

Comment: works. Thank you.@esentis

Comment: and by the way `difinition` is widely known as `definition` :-)